# CustomValidator in ASP.net is empty when Textbox.TextMode="Password"

Tags: asp.net, customvalidator

my CustomValidator in ASP.net is empty when Textbox.TextMode="Password".
I call a server-method and try to get the value.Value.

When I change the TextMode to SingleLine or MultiLine all works fine.
When I have it to Password the value is empty.

But for me there is no way to do it without textmode=password, so what to do there?

Comment: Are you performing validation client side or server side ?

Comment: It might help if you post some code.  Can you elaborate what you mean by "I call a server-method and try to get the value.Value"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of getting value from args.Value you get it from the textbox directly like:

```
protected void CustomValidator1_ServerValidate(object source, ServerValidateEventArgs args)
        {
            string pwd = txtPwd.Text;
            if (pwd == "something")
            {
                args.IsValid = false;
            }
            else
            {
                args.IsValid = true;
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe that is standard behavior for security purposes.